# nightmare run function que in while loop (let the loop wait until que is finished)

Tags: javascript, node.js, nightmare

I am trying to run nightmare in a while loop. My problem is that the while loop is not waiting for nightmare to finish.
That's my example code:

```
var Nightmare = require('nightmare');
var Screenshot = require('nightmare-screenshot');
var i = 0;

while(i < 10) {

    var nightmare = new Nightmare();
    nightmare.goto('https:/website/?id='+  i);
    nightmare.screenshot('/home/linaro/cointellect_bot/screenshot1.png');
    nightmare.use(Screenshot.screenshotSelector('screenshot' + i + '.png', 'img[id="test"]'));
    nightmare.run();
}
```

Is it possible to let the loop wait until nightmare has finished it's function queue? What other options do I have?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use a function instead of a loop:

```
var nightmare;
var Nightmare = require('nightmare');
var Screenshot = require('nightmare-screenshot');

var runNext = function (i) {
    if (i < 10) {
        nightmare = new Nightmare();
        nightmare.goto('https:/website/?id='+  i);
        nightmare.screenshot('/home/linaro/cointellect_bot/screenshot1.png');
        nightmare.use(Screenshot.screenshotSelector('screenshot' + i + '.png', 'img[id="test"]'));
        nightmare.run(function () {runNext(i+1);});        
    }
}
runNext(0);
```

`nightmare.run` accepts a callback according to this documentation: https://github.com/segmentio/nightmare#runcb

The function that is passed as an argument there gets called once nightmare is finished or errored out.

This is generally how most asynchronous things in nodejs work.

Comment: It wasn't my downvote. It worked for me thanks! I will accept as soon as i can.

Comment: The use of the callback forcing the function to be used in series is an issue for me. Also the stop condition used is probably the wrong condition to use. (It would be easy to call the other way around). If using a number for the parameter then I would expect to call ``nextRun(10)`` not ``nextRun(0)``. Finally ``nextRun`` probably could have a better name.

Answer (score 1):

Whilst you need to extract a function it is probably best to this with not just passing in a number but the full context. Your function will therefore look like

```
var screenshotPage = function(data){
  var nightmare = new Nightmare();
  nightmare.goto(data.url);
  nightmare.use(Screenshot.screenshotSelector(data.filePath, data.selector));
  nightmare.run();
}
```

You should be able to run the example like this

```
var Nightmare = require('nightmare');
var Screenshot = require('nightmare-screenshot');
var async = require('async')

var pages = [];

// You could do this recursively if you want
for(var i=0; i < 10; i++) {
    pages.push({
        url: 'https://website/?id='+ i,
        filePath: 'screenshot' + i + '.png',
        selector: 'img[id="test"]'
    });
}

var screenshotPage = function(data, callback){
  var nightmare = new Nightmare();
  nightmare.goto(data.url);
  nightmare.use(Screenshot.screenshotSelector(data.filePath, data.selector));
  nightmare.run(function(){
    callback(null);
  });
}

async.map(pages, screenshotPage, function(){
  // Here all screenshotPage functions will have been called 
  // there has been an error
});
```